# Calculating with Symbols

Tags: puzzle-identification

> **& x & = €&
>
> What is &?**
>
> Each Symbol is one Number.
> Possible answers: 0, 3 , 7 , 6

Correct answer: $6$, because $6 \times 6 = 36$

**What is the correct name of this kind of Puzzle?

Where can i get more of these?**
In Germany we use them in Aptitude Tests.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 8):

These are usually called [alphametics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphametic), but these usually have letters instead of numbers. A common example is below:

\begin{align}
&SEND\\
+&MORE\\\hline
M&ONEY
\end{align}

The equivalent for your question would be something like:

\begin{align}
&A\\
\times&A\\\hline
B&A
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are called [alphametics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphametic). You can find more just by googling them, [here's](http://www.cryptarithms.com/default.asp?pg=1) a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Puzzling has its own tag for these: [alphametic](/questions/tagged/alphametic)